# length of vector (v-2w) ? and other matrix problems

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Q1. 
If vector **v** and **w** are orthogonal unit vectors, how can I calculate the length of (**v**-**2w**) ??

Q2. Is it correct that for a matrix A and **w**=2**u**-3**v**, A**w**=2A**u**-3A**v**??

Q3. Is the following sentence true? :
If columns 1 and 2 of B are the same, then so are columns 1 and 2 of AB.

If not, what would be the correct sentence??

Answer (score 1):

The length of any vector $u$ is the square root of the dot product with itself, or $\sqrt{u \cdot u}$.

For Q1, replace $u$ above with $v-2w$, and use the distributive properties of dot product to expand it. Since $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal, $v \cdot w=0$. Since $v$ and $w$ are both unit vectors, they each have magnitude 1.

Q2) Yes.

Q3) Think about how you would get columns 1 and 2 of $AB$. To get column 1, for example, you would do the dot product of the first row of $A$ with the first column of $B$.